# CSS navbar text positioning

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navbar

I'm looking for 2 days how I can move my "Login/Register" text on my navbar to the right of the navbar so that it's on the same row as the other text/logo/spaced the same way with the logo so that it's consistent (or shift the logo so that it's stuck on the left)

I would like to post a little bit like this: https://prnt.sc/10xtn19
The logo stuck on the left or with a small spacing, Home/Forums/Store centered in the middle of my navbar and Login + register on the right with the same spacing as the logo

```css
    * {
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #3e3e3e;
}

header {
    background-color: rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.99)!important;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    left: 50%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0.9;
}


.home {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}

.home-a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}


.forums {
    
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}

.forums-a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;

}

.store {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}

.store-a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}


.register {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.register-a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;

}

.login {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.login-a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}


.login-register {
    justify-content: left;
}

.header-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 256px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-right: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

    <link rel="icon" type="img/svg+xml" href="img/favicon.svg">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  
    
    <title>Home | Kurium v4.5</title>

</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <ul class="kurium-button">
            <img class="header-logo" src="img/logo.svg">
    
            <button class="home"><a class="home-a" href="https://google.fr/">Home</a> </button>
            <button class="forums"><a class="forums-a" href="https://google.fr/">Forums</a> </button>
            <button class="store"><a class="store-a" href="https://google.fr/">Store</a> </button>
        </ul>

            <ul class="login-register">
            <!-- A remplacer par : Flexbox -->
            <li class="register" style="float:right"><a class="register-a" href="register.html">Register</a></li></button>
            <li class="login" style="float:right"><a class="login-a" href="login.html">Login</a></li></button>
        </ul>
        </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex is amazing! Try this:

```html
<header>
        <div style="display: flex;">
        
            <div style="width: 100%;">
        <ul class="kurium-button">
            <img class="header-logo" src="img/logo.svg">
    
            <button class="home"><a class="home-a" href="https://google.fr/">Home</a> </button>
            <button class="forums"><a class="forums-a" href="https://google.fr/">Forums</a> </button>
            <button class="store"><a class="store-a" href="https://google.fr/">Store</a> </button>
        </ul>
    </div>
        
        <div style="width: 20%;">
            <ul class="login-register">
            <!-- A remplacer par : Flexbox -->
            <li class="register" style="float:right"><a class="register-a" href="register.html">Register</a></li></button>
            <li class="login" style="float:right"><a class="login-a" href="login.html">Login</a></li></button>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
        </header>
```

and this:

`.login-register { display: flex; justify-content: center; }`

And try to master flex my friend.

Comment: Thanks for your help that :
<header style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
Does it have to go in my HTML?
Because here I have done this: https://prnt.sc/10xtui9
and this: https://prnt.sc/10xtumk
I get: https://prnt.sc/10xtuqm

Comment: No of course being in style and not inline is better mostly. But what is the problem with this one? I didn't get it?

Comment: The login + register is positioned below my navbar despite the suggestion you sent me it did not work

Comment: The logo didn't move but I have the impression that Home/Forums/Store is well centered on my navbar

Comment: I fixed the code. At first I misunderstood what you wanted. So here you go :)

Comment: Sorry but it still doesn't work and I admit I don't understand the changes x) https://prnt.sc/10xu4sc

Comment: Oh ok I thought you had sent above the code that I had to replace

Comment: You can change the widths of the div as you prefer.

Comment: Oh my god! Thanks man, I just understood where I screwed up and on top of that the result is almost what I want, I'll just have to make some modifications on my logo in terms of graphics I think, and to shift some elements, thanks a lot ! I validate so thank you again